# JCombobox accepting array of characters

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I want JCombobox to accept an array of characters. I can't seem to find a workaround for this. Basically, I want JCombobox to hold values '0' - '9', but as chars instead of int.

```
char[] levels = {'0', '1', '2', '3'};
skillLevelCombo = new JComboBox<Object>(levels); //Does not work
```

How do I get around this? Do I make a Character array? If so, how do I get the char values later on?

Comment: You'll want a `JComboBox<Character>` and a similar model. Then use a custom cell renderer, and you're golden.

Comment: *"..basically, I want JCombobox to hold values '0' - '9', but as chars instead of int."* ***...Why?***  Personally I'd offer a `JSpinner` wit a spinner number model and convert to char on selection.

Comment: Try using `Character[] levels = ...` and `JComboBox<Character> skillLevelCombo = new JComboBox<>(levels);` instead, `char` is considered a primitive type and isn't been autoboxed in this context because of the generics (I think)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No worries, too lazy to post an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
  Character[] levels = {'0', '1', '2', '3'};
  skillLevelCombo = new JComboBox<Character>(levels);
```

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ComboFun {
   private static JComboBox<Character> skillLevelCombo;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Character[] levels = {'0', '1', '2', '3'};
      skillLevelCombo = new JComboBox<Character>(levels); 

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, skillLevelCombo);
   }
}
```

Please note that Integers work well too:

```
  Integer[] levels = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  final JComboBox<Integer> skillLevelCombo = new JComboBox<Integer>(levels);
```